# Trying to remember a zugzwang puzzle/study position

Tags: problems, puzzles, zugzwang

I am trying to remember a puzzle position, or maybe was it originated from a real game, i dont remember.

> After Rook c8, we have a nice zugzwang, which forces black to have as only legal move Rook from a7 to a8, making it *en prise* for white's rook.

Something like (white to move):

```
7R/rp6/pk6/p7/P7/8/1K6/8 w - - 0 1
```

I would like to know where is this puzzle/game from. I'm not sure that this was the exact position, but it was quite similar.

Comment: This cries to be the end of a study. The database of Harold van der Heijden is your friend :-)

Comment: It *is* the end of a study, but slightly misremembered.
Fortunately I read *1234* early enough that I remembered this Zugzwang set-up
even with the Ka4 changed to a pawn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original position has the White King on a4, no White pawn.  It's the end of a composed study by Gorgiev that I find as #753 in Sutherland and Lommer's *1234 Modern End-Game Studies* (1938, Dover reprint 1968), pages 126 and 290.  The full study is:

```
[Title "White to move and win (Gorgiev, Pravda 1928: Mention)"]
[FEN "1k6/rp6/p7/p5B1/K7/8/8/7R w - - 0 1"]

1.Rh8+ Kc7 2.Bd8+ Kc6 3.Bb6! Kxb6 4.Rc8! 1-0
```

The final position is mutual Zugzwang: Black loses (the only legal move is Ra8, and then 5.Rxa8 wins easily) but would draw if it were White's move.